# Method does not exist or incorrect signature?

Tags: eclipse, salesforce

I am getting the method does not exist or incorrect error with this line:

```
partnerSoapSforceComWrapper.update_x(new List<Contact> (contacts));
```

The `partnerSoap`is defined below:

```
partnerSoapSforceCom.SaveResult[] update_x(sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x[] sObjects);
```

`Contact` is an `sObject`; the same with `contacts`.

My question is: how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is in Apex, `List<Contact>` will be a reference to the built in `Contact` type, and not the `Contact` type you imported from the WSDL, and so its not a descendent of the `sObject_x` type. But once you've gotten that sorted out, I expect you'll be further stuck because wsdl2apex does not support the `xsd:any` element used by the partner WSDL, so once you get it to compile, you won't be able to do anything useful.

You probably should be looking at the salesforce 2 salesforce feature to copy data between different org's in salesforce (which is a guess at what you're trying to do).

Comment: Thanks for the response, will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Either `partnerSoapSforceComWrapper` on your first line is not the correct variable name, or it doesn't have a method signature `update_x(List <Contact>)`.

Where is `partnerSoapSforceComWrapper` defined? If you post more code I could give a more definitive answer. Hopefully the above helps you find the problem.